# Running 64-bit executable in System32 from 32-bit code

Tags: c#, windows, syswow64

I am trying to run an executable from a 32-bit C# app (on a 64-bit OS), but I’m getting “The system cannot find the file specified” probably because wsqmcons.exe does not exist in C:\Windows\SySWOW64. The file does exist in System32. What is the best way to run wsqmcons.exe from code, if possible?

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-f";
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\wsqmcons.exe";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
Verify.AreEqual(0, p.ExitCode);
```

Comment: For a quick-n-dirty fix, try changing the the path to: `@"C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsqmcons.exe"`.    
See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589 for additional details/pointers that are more oriented to the Win32 API, but may help in .NET as well.

Comment: @Michael According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx it's recommended, so it's not so quick-n-dirty after all! I believe you should post this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to turn off the file system redirection on your 32 bit process with the Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection and the re-enable it with Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection.

Answer (score 1):

> A 64-bit executable file located under **%windir%\System32** cannot be
>   launched from a 32-bit process, because the file system redirector
>   redirects the path to **%windir%\SysWOW64**. ***Do not disable redirection to***
>   ***accomplish this***; use **%windir%\Sysnative** instead. For more information,
>   see [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Quote from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx